Fetch contacts by phone number wise in Swift
I am accessing all Contacts with name and phone numbers. I am getting an array of CNContact with multiple phone numbers in single CNContact, which is expected.
func fetchContacts() {
    let store = CNContactStore()
    let keysToFetch = [
        CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
        CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as any CNKeyDescriptor
    ]
    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
    var result: [CNContact] = []
    
    do {
        try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) { contact, stop in
            if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {
                result.append(contact)
            }
        }
        print(result)
    } catch let error {
        print("Fetching contacts failed: \(error)")
    }
}

Output:
[
    Contact(fullName : "John Appleseed", phoneNumbers: ["888-555-5512", "888-555-1212"]),
    Contact(fullName : "Kate Bell",      phoneNumbers: ["(555) 564-8583", "(415) 555-3695"])
]

But what I want to achieve is an array of CNContact with single phone number.
[
    Contact(fullName : "John Appleseed", phoneNumber: "888-555-5512"),
    Contact(fullName : "John Appleseed", phoneNumber: "888-555-1212"),
    Contact(fullName : "Kate Bell",      phoneNumber: "(555) 564-8583"),
    Contact(fullName : "Kate Bell",      phoneNumber: "(415) 555-3695")
]

What NSPredicate will work in this case?
NOTE: Ignore UI error, already implemented permissions, want to achieve before reading contacts (fetch request) not after reading contacts.

You can't use NSPredicate to change the output of the query, it's only meant for filtering the data. If you want a custom format for your output you are going to need a custom type
For instance
struct Contact {
    let name: String
    let phoneNumber: String
}

And then convert to that type in your loop
var resultContact: [Contact] = []
do {
    try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest) { contact, stop in
        if contact.phoneNumbers.count > 0 {
            contact.phoneNumbers.forEach { phoneNumber in
                let phoneNumber = phoneNumber.value.stringValue
                resultContact.append(Contact(name: contact.givenName + " " + contact.familyName, phoneNumber: phoneNumber))
            }
        }
    }
    print(resultContact)
} catch let error {
    print("Fetching contacts failed: \(error)")
}


Thank you for your answer. Currently, I am achieving this by custom contact object. like you mentioned. BUT I need to fetch with NSPredicate; before enumerate if possible.

My answer doesn't change that, you use the same query and predicate as in your question.

Predicates are for filtering the fetched CNContact objects, to limit the results to those that match some criteria. For example, you might use a predicate to fetch only contacts with phone numbers:
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 0")

But it won’t “split” a single CNContact into multiple entries, one for each phone number. You have to do that yourself. You can use the pattern that Joakim outlined (+1). Or, personally, I might use a flatMap method that takes an array of return values and builds an array from that:
extension CNContactStore {
    /// Flat map
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - request: The `CNContactFetchRequest`.
    ///   - transform: A closure that returns an array of values to be appended to the final results.
    /// - Returns: A flat array of all of the results.

    func flatMap<T>(request: CNContactFetchRequest, _ transform: (CNContact, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> [T]) throws -> [T] {
        var results: [T] = []

        try enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
            results += transform(contact, stop)
        }

        return results
    }

    /// Map
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - request: The `CNContactFetchRequest`.
    ///   - transform:  A closure that returns a value to be appended to the final results.
    /// - Returns: A flat array of all of the results.

    func map<T>(request: CNContactFetchRequest, _ transform: (CNContact, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> T) throws -> [T] {
        var results: [T] = []

        try enumerateContacts(with: request) { contact, stop in
            results.append(transform(contact, stop))
        }

        return results
    }
}

That’s both a flatMap (for your use-case where you may want to return multiple objects for a given CNContact), as well as a more traditional map rendition (not used here, but is my typical use-case).
Anyway, you can then use it like so:
let keys = [
    CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
    CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName)
]

let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys)
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 0")
request.sortOrder = .userDefault

let formatter = CNContactFormatter()
formatter.style = .fullName

do {
    let results = try store.flatMap(request: request) { contact, _ in
        contact.phoneNumbers.compactMap { phone -> Contact? in
            guard let name = formatter.string(from: contact) else { return nil }
            return Contact(fullName: name, phoneNumber: phone.value.stringValue)
        }
    }

    …
} catch {
    print("Failed to fetch contacts with phone numbers:", error)
}

That returned:
Contact(fullName: "John Appleseed", phoneNumber: "888-555-5512")
Contact(fullName: "John Appleseed", phoneNumber: "888-555-1212")
Contact(fullName: "Kate Bell", phoneNumber: "(555) 564-8583")
Contact(fullName: "Kate Bell", phoneNumber: "(415) 555-3695")


By the way, while I show the use of sortOrder of userDefault (which is nice, because it sorts based upon first or last name based upon the user’s preference specified in the Settings app), we should note that the contacts on the simulator may not be sorted correctly. I find that the simulator won’t sort correctly unless you edit the contacts (even if the edits are unrelated to the contact’s name). This is just a bug in the simulator’s contacts.
